# Different behaviour programmatically defined NSLayoutConstraints versus Storyboard constraints with 'greaterThanOrEqual'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm getting different (unexpected) behaviour with NSLayoutConstraints programmatically versus configuring the constraints with a Storyboard or Xib. The exact same constraints are used.

What I'm trying to accomplish is: a UILabel to resize to its intrinsic content size when constraining it to the superview's center, with leading and trailing constraints relation set to 'greaterThanOrEqual'.

**1. The *Storyboard* works as expected. It resizes the UILabel to its intrinsic content size:**
[image]

[image]

**2.The programmatic approach displays the UILabel in full width instead with `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.` warning:**

[image]

I've created an example project where it illustrates the issue: https://github.com/thomasneuteboom/temp-layout-constraints-issue.

Can someone point me the obvious thing I'm missing here? Is the storyboard giving the UILabel additional (hidden) behaviour?

**Code:**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let programmaticallyLabel = UILabel()
        programmaticallyLabel.text = "Programmatically example"
        programmaticallyLabel.textColor = .white
        programmaticallyLabel.backgroundColor = .blue
        self.view.addSubview(programmaticallyLabel)

//        programmaticallyLabel.sizeToFit()

        // Setup constraints.
        programmaticallyLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: programmaticallyLabel, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.greaterThanOrEqual, toItem: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 15)
        let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: programmaticallyLabel, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.greaterThanOrEqual, toItem: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 15)
        let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: programmaticallyLabel, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: programmaticallyLabel, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        self.view.addConstraints([leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint, horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint])
    }
```

Comment: You had better to use NSLayoutConstraint.activate

Comment: You really should be using layout anchors. So much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need it `lessThanOrEqual` with trailing

```
let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: programmaticallyLabel, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.lessThanOrEqual, toItem: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -15)
```

if you see it in IB you'll find that with trailing the first item is the superview's trailing and  it's `greaterThanOrEqualTo` but in code you reverse the first item so you have to reverse the relation , the order here is very important

[image]

---

Btw use

```
programmaticallyLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false 
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    programmaticallyLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 15),
    programmaticallyLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -15),
    programmaticallyLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor ),
    programmaticallyLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor )
])
```

Answer (score 2):

From your Main.storyboard:

```
<label opaque="NO" 
       userInteractionEnabled="NO" 
       contentMode="left" 
       horizontalHuggingPriority="251" 
       verticalHuggingPriority="251" 
       text="Storyboard example" 
       textAlignment="natural" 
       lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" 
       baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" 
       adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO"
       translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" 
       id="HPb-Ly-SNL">

<constraints>
    <constraint firstItem="HPb-Ly-SNL" 
                firstAttribute="centerY" 
                secondItem="fsQ-UL-Fbk" 
                secondAttribute="centerY" 
                id="0Up-NL-qsu"/>
    <constraint firstItem="fsQ-UL-Fbk" 
                firstAttribute="trailing" 
                relation="greaterThanOrEqual" 
                secondItem="HPb-Ly-SNL"
                secondAttribute="trailing" 
                constant="15" 
                id="7xt-tj-mzn"/>
    <constraint firstItem="HPb-Ly-SNL" 
                firstAttribute="leading" 
                relation="greaterThanOrEqual" 
                secondItem="fsQ-UL-Fbk" 
                secondAttribute="leading" 
                constant="15" 
                id="Gyk-6R-ri3"/>
    <constraint firstItem="HPb-Ly-SNL" 
                firstAttribute="centerX" 
                secondItem="fsQ-UL-Fbk" 
                secondAttribute="centerX" 
                id="axh-b8-nGS"/>
</constraints>
<viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="fsQ-UL-Fbk"/>
```

You have (I just added spaces and remove unnecessary parts):

```
let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: programmaticallyLabel,
                                           attribute: .leading,
                                           relatedBy: .greaterThanOrEqual,
                                           toItem: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide,
                                           attribute: .leading,
                                           multiplier: 1,
                                           constant: 15)
let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: programmaticallyLabel,
                                            attribute: .trailing,
                                            relatedBy: .greaterThanOrEqual,
                                            toItem: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide,
                                            attribute: .trailing,
                                            multiplier: 1,
                                            constant: 15)
let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: programmaticallyLabel,
                                              attribute: .centerX,
                                              relatedBy: .equal,
                                              toItem: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide,
                                              attribute: .centerX,
                                              multiplier: 1,
                                              constant: 0)
let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: programmaticallyLabel,
                                            attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal,
                                            toItem: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide,
                                            attribute: .centerY,
                                            multiplier: 1,
                                            constant: 0)
```

Almost each ones concurs, BUT, there is a difference.

```
let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: programmaticallyLabel,
                                            attribute: .trailing,
                                            relatedBy: .greaterThanOrEqual,
                                            toItem: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide,
                                            attribute: .trailing,
                                            multiplier: 1,
                                            constant: 15)
```

vs

```
<constraint firstItem="fsQ-UL-Fbk" 
            firstAttribute="trailing" 
            relation="greaterThanOrEqual" 
            secondItem="HPb-Ly-SNL"
            secondAttribute="trailing" 
            constant="15" 
            id="7xt-tj-mzn"/>
```

**The order is different.** 
You can use negative values as constant, and if in Interface Builder you choose to switch the item order, the value becomes negative/positive.
Here, in the Storyboard, the first item (id) is the SafeArea, and the label is the second one. In code, it's the reverse.
So you can use a constant -15 instead, or change the order by code of the two items. Also, the greaterThanOrEqual might need a change (to `lessThanOrEqual`, because it's a trailing).

In Storyboard:

Currently you have:
[image: Current Situation]

You can change:
[image: Reverse Order in Interface]

You'll have:

[image: Reversed Value]

Opening the XML of the Storyboard:

```
<constraint firstItem="HPb-Ly-SNL" 
        firstAttribute="trailing" 
        relation="lessThanOrEqual" 
        secondItem="fsQ-UL-Fbk" 
        secondAttribute="trailing" 
        constant="-15" 
        id="7xt-tj-mzn"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your constraints is wrong. The constant should be -15 and the relation should be lessThanOrEqual:

```
    let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: programmaticallyLabel, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.lessThanOrEqual, toItem: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -15)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to give lessThanOrEqual to constraint than change the trailingConstraint to this

```
let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.greaterThanOrEqual, toItem: programmaticallyLabel, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 15)
```